# How to change the argument of function in a loop (Python)?

Tags: python, loops, statsmodels

In Python, suppose I have a pandas dataframe with columns labeled Y, X1, X2, X3.
I run an OLS regression on Y with X1, X2, X3.
I want to store the coefficients from the regression in a list using a loop.
How do I change the argument of a function in a loop?
The following code does not work.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

ols = sm.OLS(df[['Y']],(df[['X_1','X_2','X_3']]))
olsfit = ols.fit(cov_type='HC0')

coef = []

for i in range(4):
    coef.append(olsfit.params.X_i)
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop? the model object has `params` attribute containing coefficients for all model parameters.

Comment: That's a good point. Say there are many other regressors, e.g. Z_1, ... Z_100, and I want to extract just the X_1, ..., X_N coefficients?

Comment: params is in this case a pandas.Series and you can just index into it to select some individual parameters, or convert to numpy array and use numpy indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is sufficient to get your code working, but if you just need to access a property dynamically, use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
# Also using comprehension notation
coef = [
  getattr(olsfit.params, 'X_' + str(i))
  for i in range(4)
]
```

That said, I would suggest you follow ako's answer

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating over an integer to construct regressor names, just use **actual** names in the statsmodels `RegressionResultsWrapper` `params` attribute (which is a neat `pd.Series`, indexed on regressor names) to filter as appropriate - like so:

```
olsfit.params[olsfit.params.index.str.contains('^X_')]
```